# C# Initialize Objects using Task

Tags: c#, task

I have some third-party class' that (for some reason) are heavy to initialize. Then I thought if I could Initialize them in parallel I could cut down on the loading time.

Shouldn't this be all fine?
Or are there something that i'm not taking into account?
I don't get any errors however I can see that the "rest of the code" outputs a different and wrong result from when I just Initialize them normally.
Could it be something inside the third-party class's that don't like to be Initialized in parallel?

I have a `base class` and several `child class's`. Inside my `child Class's` is where I  Initialize the third-party class'

My code looks something like this:

```
public ChildClass1 test1;
public ChildClass2 test2;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


Stopwatch MainWatch = new Stopwatch();
MainWatch.Start();

Task task1 = new Task(() => test1 = new ChildClass1());
task1.Start();

Task task2 = new Task(() => test2 = new ChildClass2());
task2.Start();

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
MainWatch.Stop();

//Rest of the code...
```

**(Edit)**
After reading the link from the comment im now doing it the way shown below. It is working and I'm gaining about 25% in load time. The question is now, it is actually running in parallel?

```
public ChildClass1 test1;
public ChildClass2 test2;

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


Stopwatch MainWatch = new Stopwatch();
MainWatch.Start();

await Task.Run(() => test1 = new ChildClass1());

await Task.Run(() => test2 = new ChildClass2());


await Task.WhenAll();
MainWatch.Stop();

//Rest of the code...
```

Comment: [Tasks are (still) not threads and async is not parallel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/)

Comment: reading for you: https://www.wintellect.com/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Comment: I've start reading right away

Comment: Even if you do apply multi-threading correctly, you must be sure the third-party code is thread safe.

Comment: If you want to create a Task and start it, then you can use `Task.StartNew` .

Comment: @marsze
Could you show me how I do apply multi-threading correctly in my example?

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be something inside the third-party class's that don't like to be Initialized in parallel?

Sure. All kinds of things. Maybe it's not thread safe. Seeing how you use it in a UI app, maybe it contains UI elements, those don't like to be created in a non-UI thread, even if it's thread safe.

Only the vendor of your 3rd party component can tell you. Provide them with [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so they can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that the initialization might indeed *not* be thread-safe (only the vendor knows), if they really take so long to initialize, then maybe parallelization is still not the best solution, as there would still be a lot of work to do.

Unfortunately, your example is very generic. So it's not clear what you actually want to do. If the work to perform is so heavy, you probably shouldn't do it all inside the button-click. The click should only trigger the operation, then you could show a load indicator on the UI for example (maybe disable the button while the work is in progress), and finally do whatever it is you want to do once the operation is complete.